# In Left 4 Dead 2, how do I join a server by IP?

Tags: pc, steam, left-4-dead-2, source-engine

My friend was playing some 10v10 on L4D2 the other night, I did a search of google and found a bunch of IP addresses for these 10v10 servers, but how do I join them?  There is nowhere in game to enter an IP or anything like that.

Thanks!

PS: 10v10 is awesome

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to join by IP, you're going to have to use a feature called the Developer Console. You can find it under Keyboard Settings. Enable the Developer Console feature there.

Then, when you want to join a server, press the <kbd>~</kbd> key, that's usually the key next to <kbd>1</kbd> on your keyboard and enter `connect <IP>` into the prompt, for example `connect 123.45.6.7`. You'll then join the server.